# Stored Procedure Passing a Null into Dataset upon Refresh -- SSRS / Oracle 11g

Tags: sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures, reporting-services, oracle11g

I have a report built in Visual Studio 2012 from a stored procedure created in a DB I have no access to (Oracle 11g). The SP was updated to include 3 new columns that needed to be added to the report, and a beginning / end date parm. The report ran without incident prior to this update. After the SP was updated to add those columns and the additional date parm (defined in the where clause found in the code below), I attempted to reload the RDL and refresh the SP.

I received the following error:

> ORA-2060: An Error was encountered - Parameter "Registration Status" is NULL.

I have the parms manually defined in my parameter list, and provided a default value of 'All' for the Status parameter, with an available value list of other possible values. The SQL statement has a `NVL(`  to replace any NULL values with 'Not Registered' for status, so I don't understand why it is throwing this error upon my attempt to refresh the SP in the Dataset in VS.

I have deleted and re-added my Data Source, attempted to re-add the Dataset with the new SP after deleting the old one, I have deleted my DATA files in my cache, and I have reverted to the old report RDL and attempted to refresh the dataset inside of that version.

Other than adding a non-defined date field for my to and from dates, and adding cosmetic changes to the table to house the 3 new datafields - I changed nothing from the source report.

What is causing the error?

SP Code follows:

```
BEGIN

-- Check Parameters...

fmccd      := UPPER(P_FMC_CODE);
fleetcd    := UPPER(P_FLEET_CODE);
status     := UPPER(P_STATUS);
start_date := TRUNC(P_FROM_DATE);
end_date   := TRUNC(P_TO_DATE);
daysdelinq := NVL(P_DELINQ,0);
hnode      := UPPER(P_HIERARCHY_NODE);
hnodestmt  := ' AND ((hn.full_code LIKE ''';

parm_found := INSTR(fmccd,'''',1);

IF parm_found >= 1 THEN
   RAISE FMC_CODE_INVALID;
END IF;

parm_found := INSTR(fleetcd,'''',1);

IF parm_found >= 1 THEN
   RAISE FLEET_CODE_INVALID;
END IF;


IF fmccd <> 'ALL' THEN
    SELECT count(*) into parm_found 
      FROM fmcs
    WHERE fmc_code = fmccd;

   IF parm_found != 1 THEN 
      RAISE  FMC_CODE_NOT_FOUND;      
   END IF;   

END IF;


IF fleetcd <> 'ALL' THEN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO parm_found 
       FROM fleets fl 
          JOIN fmcs f on f.fmc_id = fl.fmc_id
    WHERE fl.fleet_code = fleetcd;

   IF parm_found = 0 THEN 
      RAISE FLEET_CODE_INVALID;      
   END IF;   

END IF;

IF status IS NULL THEN
   RAISE STATUS_IS_NULL;
END IF;

IF hnode IS NULL THEN
  RAISE HIERARCHY_IS_NULL;
ELSE  
  IF SUBSTR(hnode,LENGTH(hnode), 1) <> '|' THEN
     RAISE HIERARCHY_NOT_FOUND ;  
  END IF;
END IF;


IF start_date IS NULL THEN
   start_date := SYSDATE ;
END IF;

IF end_date IS NULL THEN
   end_date := SYSDATE ;
END IF;



--Base SQL statement
sqlstmt := 
'SELECT f.fmc_code                                        fmc,
        fl.fleet_code                                     client,
        hn.full_code                                      hierarchy_node_id,
        d.driver_number                                   driver_id,
        TRUNC(dn.mailed_date)                             registration_req_date,
        TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(dn.mailed_date)            days_delinquent,
        v.vehicle_number                                  vehicle_id,
        NVL(dp.last_name,d.last_name)                     last,
        NVL(dp.first_name,d.first_name)                   first,
        NVL(dp.address_1,d.address_1)                     address1,
        NVL(dp.address_2,d.address_2)                     address2,
        NVL(dp.city,d.city)                               city, 
        NVL(dp.state_province_code,d.state_province_code) state,
        NVL(dp.zip_postal_code,d.zip_postal_code)         zip,
        NVL(dp.country_code,d.country_code)               country,
        NVL(dp.phone,d.phone)                             phone,
        NVL(dp.cell,d.cell)                               mobile,
        NVL(dp.email,d.email)                             email,
        CASE WHEN (TRUNC(sysdate) BETWEEN vs_viologics.start_date AND NVL(vs_viologics.end_date,sysdate + 1))  THEN ''ENROLLED'' 
             WHEN (TRUNC(sysdate) BETWEEN vs_platepass.start_date AND NVL(vs_platepass.end_date,sysdate + 1))  THEN ''ENROLLED''
             ELSE ''UNENROLLED'' END                      enrollment_status,
        NVL(DECODE(dp.account_status,''ACTIVATED'',''REGISTERED'',''REGISTERED'',''PENDING ACTIVATION'',NULL),''NOT REGISTERED'')  registration_status,
        dp.registration_date                              registration_date,
        vs_platepass.pt_enrolled_date                     pers_tolling_enrollment_date,
        vs_viologics.start_date                           viologics_enrollment_date
   FROM drivers d
   LEFT JOIN driver_vehicles dv ON d.driver_id = dv.driver_id
   JOIN fmcs f on d.fmc_id = f.fmc_id
   JOIN fleets fl on d.fleet_id = fl.fleet_id
   LEFT JOIN vehicles v ON dv.vehicle_id = v.vehicle_id
   LEFT JOIN vehicle_services vs_viologics ON v.vehicle_id = vs_viologics.vehicle_id
   LEFT JOIN vehicle_service_types vst_viologics ON vst_viologics.service_type = vs_viologics.service_type AND vst_viologics.service_class = ''' || 'VIOLOGICS' || '''
   LEFT JOIN vehicle_services vs_platepass ON v.vehicle_id = vs_platepass.vehicle_id AND vs_platepass.personal_tolling_enabled = 1
   LEFT JOIN vehicle_service_types vst_platepass ON vst_platepass.service_type = vs_platepass.service_type AND vst_platepass.service_class = ''' || 'PLATEPASS' || '''
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT vehicle_id ,max(hierarchy_node_id) hierarchy_node_id FROM vehicle_nodes GROUP BY vehicle_id) vn ON v.vehicle_id = vn.vehicle_id
   LEFT JOIN driver_profiles dp ON d.driver_profile_id = dp.driver_profile_id
   LEFT JOIN hierarchy_nodes hn ON vn.hierarchy_node_id = hn.hierarchy_node_id
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT MIN(mailed_date) mailed_date, driver_id FROM driver_notices WHERE mailed_date IS NOT NULL GROUP BY driver_id) dn ON dn.driver_id = d.driver_id  
  WHERE (nvl(dv.end_date,sysdate + 1) > sysdate) 
    AND (vst_viologics.service_class = ''' || 'VIOLOGICS' || ''' OR (vst_platepass.service_class = ''' || 'PLATEPASS' || ''' AND vs_platepass.personal_tolling_enabled = 1))
    AND ''' || status || ''' IN (''ALL'',NVL(DECODE(dp.account_status,''ACTIVATED'',''REGISTERED'',''REGISTERED'',''PENDING ACTIVATION'',NULL),''NOT REGISTERED''))
    AND (((' || daysdelinq || ' = 0)) OR (TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(dn.mailed_date) >= ' || daysdelinq || ') AND (d.driver_profile_id IS NULL))   
    AND ((''' || fmccd || ''' = ''ALL'') OR (f.fmc_code = ''' ||  fmccd || '''))
    AND ((''' || fleetcd || ''' = ''ALL'') OR (fl.fleet_code = ''' ||  fleetcd || '''))
    AND (TRUNC(dn.mailed_date) BETWEEN ''' || start_date || ''' AND ''' || end_date || ''')' ;

EXCEPTION


WHEN FMC_CODE_NOT_FOUND   THEN
     raise_application_error(-20010,'An error was encountered - ' ||
                                    'Parameter "FMC Code" is Invalid.') ;

WHEN FLEET_CODE_INVALID   THEN
     raise_application_error(-20020,'An error was encountered - ' ||
                                    'Parameter "Fleet Code" is Invalid.') ;

WHEN FMC_CODE_INVALID   THEN
     raise_application_error(-20030,'An error was encountered - ' ||
                                    'Parameter "FMC Code" is Invalid.') ;

WHEN HIERARCHY_NOT_FOUND   THEN
     raise_application_error(-20040,'An error was encountered - ' ||
                                    'Parameter "Hierarchy node is Invalid.') ;

WHEN HIERARCHY_IS_NULL THEN
     raise_application_error(-20050,'An error was encountered - ' ||
                                    'Parameter "Hierarchy Node" is NULL.') ;   

WHEN STATUS_IS_NULL THEN
     raise_application_error(-20060,'An error was encountered - ' ||
                                    'Parameter "Registration Status" is NULL.') ;

WHEN OTHERS THEN
     raise_application_error(-20100,'An ERROR was encountered - '||SQLCODE||
                                    ' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM) ;   

END;
```

Comment: Can you get your DBA (since you mentioned you have no access) to run the embedded SQL (you'll have to provide the parameters) to see what results you get?

Comment: The user-defined STATUS_IS_NULL exception is getting raised by the value check that happens before the query is called - so don't worry about the query at this point. For whatever reason the P_STATUS parameter is seen to be null.

Comment: The DBA did run a values test with these parms:  

VAR x REFCURSOR;
EXEC  DRIVER_REGISTRATION_RPT ('GE', 'ALL', 'ALL', TO_DATE('11/01/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('12/01/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 5,  'GE-GE-GELEV1%|GE%|GE-GE%|', :x);
PRINT x;    All cases were successful

Comment: @MichaelBroughton - should there be a NVL replacement somewhere before the query to remove any possible NULLS that are flagged before the query is kicked off?

Comment: If you have a default value, then yes do an NVL. If the correct behavior is to exit with an error then leave it as is.